# Magento 2: Cannot change less variables

Tags: magento2.2, theme, less, magento2.2.6

I have a problem with a custom theme in Magento. I am trying to change some variables for less. But nothing that i change has any effect on the output css.

I followed https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_mode.html or https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html to change the variables. But is has no effect.

I cleared all the caches (`cache:clean` & `cache:flush`), deleted all fiiles in `pub/static/*` and did re-deploy all static files for the theme.

Basically i have a simple theme inheriting from Luma theme (`<parent>Magento/luma</parent>`). All my other changes, custom js, css and a custom of layout changes in `Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` appear just fine. The files i created:

`<theme_dir>/web/css/source/_extend.less`:

```
.action {
    &.primary {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

`<theme_dir>/web/css/source/_theme.less`:

```
@button-primary__color: @color-white;
@button-primary__hover__color: @color-white;
@button-primary__background: @color-orange-red1;
@button-primary__hover__background: @color-orange-red4;
@button-primary__border: 1px solid @color-orange-red2;
@button-primary__hover__border: 1px solid @color-orange-red2;
```

I have Magento 2.2.6, Server-Side Less Compilation is set.

**EDIT SOLVED**: Sorry to bother you guys. Somehow i needed to manually remove `var/view_preprocessed` directory in order to make changes appear. That's only half documented in the links i provided...

Comment: Do you use varnish for caching by any chance? If so, flush varnish cache too.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually i think it was my bad. Somehow i needed to manually remove var/view_preprocessed.